# How can I set a font size smaller than \tiny in lstlisting?

Tags: beamer, listings, fontsize

I'm writing a presentation using LaTeX and `beamer`. In some slides I put an image and some code using the `listings` package and the `lstlisting` environment. I'd like to use a font size smaller than `\tiny` for the codes. How can I set that?

Thank you in advance for the answers.

Comment: Beamer defines also `\Tiny` and `\TINY` for very small text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define (for ease of use and re-use) a `\srcsize` command that sets an arbitrary font size (here 5pt for example)

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\srcsize}{\@setfontsize{\srcsize}{5pt}{5pt}}
\makeatother
```

and then in the style, you can use to set the size for the basic style:

```
basicstyle={\ttfamily\srcsize}
```

(adapt for other font families)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, `tiny` was too large, `TINY` too small, and the previous answer threw a number of errors that I didn't care to understand! I ended up with the following solution ([source](https://www.sascha-frank.com/Faq/tiny.html)):

```
{\fontsize{4}{12} \selectfont smaller than tiny}
```